# Simplifying the sum of terms that are "polynomial fractions"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to simplify:

$$\left(\frac{z^2-2}{1+2z}\right)^2 \;+ \;\left(\frac{z^2-2}{1+2z}\right)$$

I get $2z^4-8z^2+8$ in the numerator when I know it should be $((z^2-2) (z^2+2 z-1))$.

Comment: Don't use the title and the question box as one. The title is supposed to be descriptive and the question should have all the details. Please consider editing your question.

Answer (score 4):

$$\left(\frac{z^2-2}{1+2z}\right)^2-\left(\frac{z^2-2}{1+2z}\right)=\frac{(z^2-2)^2+(z^2-2)(1+2z)}{(1+2z)^2}$$
$$=\frac{(z^2-2)(z^2-2+1+2z)}{(1+2z)^2}$$ (taking $z^2-2$ common in the numerator)

So,$$\left(\frac{z^2-2}{1+2z}\right)^2-\left(\frac{z^2-2}{1+2z}\right)=\frac{(z^2-2)(z^2+2z-1)}{(1+2z)^2}$$

More generally, $\frac{a^2}{b^2}-\frac ab=\frac{a^2-ab}{b^2}=\frac{a(a-b)}{b^2}$

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes I can't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: @Ian, my pleasure. Always keep an eye on the required expression.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\frac{z^2-2}{1+2z}\right)^2+\left(\frac{z^2-2}{1+2z}\right)\;\;=\;\;\frac{(z^2-2)^2}{(1+2z)^2}+\frac{(z^2-2)}{(1+2z)}$$ 
$$=\frac{(z^2-2)^2+(z^2-2)(1+2z)}{(1+2z)^2}$$ 
$$=\frac{(z^2-2)\;[(z^2-2)+(1+2z)]}{(1+2z)^2}$$ 
$$=\frac{(z^2-2)(z^2+2z-1)}{(1+2z)^2}$$

---

Note that in general, $$\dfrac{m^2}{n^2} + \dfrac mn = \dfrac {m^2 + mn}{n^2} = \dfrac{m(m+n)}{n^2}.\;$$

Comment: Thanks! Of course I'm not squaring the numerator but I should multiply it by $(1+2z)$ Thank you.

Comment: Ian, You're welcome!!